# Disabling caching in Fluent Nhibernate for a specific override

Tags: fluent-nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate-mapping

We're using convention based mapping with Fluent NHibernate. The mapping looks like so:

```
            .Conventions.Add
            (
                Table.Is(x => string.Concat(x.EntityType.Name.ToLower(), "s")),
                PrimaryKey.Name.Is(x => "Id"),
                DefaultLazy.Always(),
                DefaultCascade.SaveUpdate(),
                AutoImport.Never(),
                Cache.Is(x => x.ReadWrite())
            )
```

For most of our objects this is perfect but on certain objects I wish to disable the 2nd level cache. However it doesn't appear that I can do this. There is no fluent option for Cache.None. I've even tried Not.Cache() but that didn't work either.

Has anyone got any ideas on how I can disable the cache for certain selected model objects?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I managed to find it after some digging around jogged an idea:

1. Remove the shortcut  `Cache.Is(x => x.ReadWrite()`
2. Create a new convention class:

```
public class CacheableConvention: IClassConventionAcceptance, IClassConvention 
{
    public void Accept(IAcceptanceCriteria criteria)
    {
        criteria.Expect(x => x.EntityType.IsNotAny(typeof(Content), typeof(InstanceSetting), typeof(Profanity))); 
    }

    public void Apply(IClassInstance instance)
    {
        instance.Cache.ReadWrite();
    }
}
```

3. Add the convention to the AutoMappings.
4. Done!